# Updating State before using REST APIs

Tags: react-native, rest, react-hooks, fetch-api

I wish to dynamically set states to some value before using the state in a REST API Post call. The issue is that setState hook is asynchronous and I can't seem to find a way to ensure that the states are updated before the REST API is called.

```
const [methodName, setMethodName] = useState("");
const [telemetryState, setTelemetryState] = useState("PAUSE");
const [selectedDevice, setSelectedDevice] = useState('');

const sendMessage = async () => {
    await fetch ('http://localhost:3000/...', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'method': methodName, 
      }),
      headers: {
        'device': selectedDevice
      }
    })
    .then((response) => console.log("response: " + response))
    .then((data) => console.log("data: " + data))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
    });
  };

  const controlDevice = () => {
    if (telemetryState == "PAUSE") {
      setMethodName("Pause");
      setTelemetryState("START");
    }
    else{
      setMethodName("Play");
      setTelemetryState("PAUSE");
    }
    
    sendMessage();
  }
  
  const selectDevice = (device) => {
    setSelectedDevice(device);
  };
  ...

  return (
    <Input 
      w={200}
      placeholder="Device" 
      marginBottom={2}
      marginTop={2}
      onChangeText={selectDevice}
    />
    <Button 
      title="Telemetry"
      onPress={controlDevice}
      style={styles.button}
    >
      {telemetryState}
    </Button>
  );
```

I know that statically setting the body and header will work, but I do wish to make it dynamic if possible. I have been thinking about using useEffect somehow, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into onClick as I have it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is you want to get the latest values of `methodName` and `selectedDevice` when calling the `sendMessage()` function. You can pass the parameters to the `sendMessage()` function instead of using the `methodName` component state.

In this way, the `sendMessage` function can be put outside of the component.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const sendMessage = async (params) => {
  console.log("sendMessage params:", params);
  // await fetch("http://localhost:3000", {
  //   method: "POST",
  //   body: JSON.stringify({
  //     method: params.methodName
  //   }),
  //   headers: {
  //     device: params.selectedDevice
  //   }
  // })
  //   .then((response) => console.log("response: " + response))
  //   .then((data) => console.log("data: " + data))
  //   .catch((error) => {
  //     console.error(error.message);
  //   });
};

export default function App() {
  const [telemetryState, setTelemetryState] = useState("PAUSE");
  const [selectedDevice, setSelectedDevice] = useState("");

  const controlDevice = () => {
    if (telemetryState === "PAUSE") {
      setTelemetryState("START");
      sendMessage({ methodName: "Pause", selectedDevice });
    } else {
      setTelemetryState("PAUSE");
      sendMessage({ methodName: "Play", selectedDevice });
    }
  };

  const selectDevice = (e) => {
    setSelectedDevice(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input placeholder="Device" onChange={selectDevice} />
      <button title="Telemetry" onClick={controlDevice}>
        {telemetryState}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76907472-jcr85g?file=/src/App.js)